# Prove that taking the orthogonal projection of a vector is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $X$, and define $T:X\to Y$ as

$$Tx = Proj_Y x$$

Then I want to check that $T$ is continuous. So I did the following, I took a converging sequence $(x_n) \in X$ with limit $x$, then I want to prove that $(Tx_n) \to Tx$. To this end I considered that $Tx_i=y_i$ and $Tx=y$, therefore

$$||y_n-y||=||y_n-x_n+x_n-y|| <||y_n-x_n||+||x_n-y||<||y^{*}-x_n||+||x_n-y||$$

Now,since the last inequality holds for all $y^{*} \in Y$ we pick this point such that $||y^{*}-x_n||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, so we get

$$||y^{*}-x_n||+||x_n-y||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+||x_n-x+x-y||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+||x_n-x||+||x-y^{**}||$$

and by the same argument as above, but know with $x$ we finally get:

$$\frac{\epsilon}{3}+||x_n-x||+||x-y^{**}||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$$

The thing is that I am not sure of my above proof, in the part of choosing those $y^{*}$ and $y^{**}$.

I was thinking to use the Pythagoras identity, but I don't know how.

Can someone help me to prove correctly the above result please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

> **Note**

Thm. Let $Y$ a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $X$. then, for  $x ∈ X$, there exists a unique $y_ 0 ∈ Y$ such that
$$||x − y_ 0 || ≤ ||x − y||$$
for all $y ∈ Y$ . This is, $y _0$ is the nearest vector in $Y$ to $x$. We call $y_0$ the orthogonal projection of $x$ in $Y$

Comment: That's not true for all $y^*$, only the $y^*$ that are in $Y$, and there is no reason to assume that $x_n$ is within $\epsilon/3$ of that subspace.

Comment: Ok :) so how can I fix it? Can you provide an answer please? Thanks :)

Comment: But I just want $y^{*} \in Y$ right?

Comment: Since you haven't defined the prohection, as I noted in my first comment, I can't help you. You don't want $y^*$ at all - this proof is flawed.

Comment: Ok, let me define the orthogonal projection :), just a second

Comment: Ready I have edited my post :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: Have you already proven that the orthogonal projection is linear?

Comment: Well. no, in fact I have only proved that is unque and the existance :)

Comment: Or how do you prove that $T$ is linear?

Comment: You prove linearity using unicity.

Comment: Ok, so if $T$ is linear inmediatly we get continuity right?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint (for a complete proof of the result).**

I suppose that you define $Tx = Proj_Y x=p_Y(x)$ as the point at smallest distance of $x$ belonging to $Y$. By the [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem), $p_Y(x)$ exists and is uniques as $Y$ is supposed to be closed.

Now you can prove that a point in $Y$ is equal to $p_Y(x)$ if and only if $$\mathcal{Re} \langle x-p_Y(x),y-p_Y(x) \rangle \le 0 \text{ for all } y \in Y.$$

Based on that, you can prove that for $u,v \in X$, you have $$\Vert p_Y(u)-p_Y(v)\Vert \le \Vert u - v \Vert \text{ for all } u,v \in X \tag{1}.$$ To do so, take $$z=u-v-(p_Y(u)-p_Y(v))=(u-p_Y(u))-(v-p_Y(v))$$ You can write $u-v=p_Y(u)-p_Y(v) + z$ and prove that $$\Vert u-v \Vert^2=\Vert p_Y(u)-p_Y(v) \Vert^2 + \Vert z \Vert^2 + 2 \mathcal{Re} \langle z, p_Y(u)-p_Y(v) \rangle $$ with $\mathcal{Re} \langle z, p_Y(u)-p_Y(v) \rangle  \ge 0$ considering the paragraph above.

Inequality (1) proves that the projection is continuous.

Comment: Is there a easiest way to get the result?

Comment: Or how can you prove your first claim?

Comment: @user162343 Maybe... but I don't know it! Everything is much simpler if you consider finite dimensional spaces, but I imagine it is not your assumption. You can "see" the inequality $\mathcal{Re} \langle x-p_Y(x),y-p_Y(x) \rangle \le 0 \text{ for all } y \in Y$ with a drawing and convince yourself it is true with the proof! By the way all this is true not only when $Y$ is a closed subspace, but also when $Y$ is just supposed to be a closed convex of $Y$.

Comment: Ok, because I was thinking to do this as it goes, just doing the difference of my post as small as I want and I am sure your proof is right, but the thing is that is a little advanced for me :), so that is the question.

Comment: I rewrote a bit the answer to make steps easier to understand... Hopefully.

Comment: @user162343 $\color{red}{\textbf{I find a simple froof }}$

from [real and complex analysis, theorem 4.11, page 80] by rudin, we know that for Hilbert space H and $x\in H$, we have
$$\|x\|^2=\|P_Y(x)\|^2+\|x-P_Y(x)\|^2$$
this means that
$$ \|P_Y(x)\|\leq  \|x\| $$
and hence, $  P_Y(x) $ is continuous.

Comment: @Amirhosseinhadadian Unfortunately that proof is tacitly assuming linearity of the projection operator, so it is not quite as simple as it seems.  In general, knowing $||f(x)||\leq ||x||$ does not imply continuity of $f$, you also need $f$ to be linear.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an answer to the question in comments - "How do you prove that projection is linear?"

Claim (1):

> $T(Tx)=Tx$

Claim (2):

> $Tx$ is the unique element of $Y$ such that for all $y\in Y$, $\langle y,x-Tx\rangle = 0 $.

(1) is trivial.

(2) requires more work. If $\langle y,x-Tx\rangle\neq 0$ for some $y\in Y$, then you can move in the direction $y$ from $Tx$ to get closer to $x$. I leave the details of that proof to you.

Showing uniquess: if $y_0\in Y$ has the above property then $x-Tx=x-y_0-(Tx-y_0)$ and:

$$\|x-Tx\|^2 = \|x-y_0\|^2 -2\langle x-y_0, Tx-y_0\rangle + \|Tx-y_0\|^2$$

But $\langle x-y_0, y_0-Tx\rangle=0$ by our assumptions, since $y_0-Tx\in Y$, which shows that $y_0$ is at least as close to $x$ as $Tx$ was. Since you've already shown that the definition of projection gives a unique element, this means $y_0=Tx$.

---

The characterization in (2) is what lets you show that $T$ is linear - that $T(x_1+x_2)=T(x_1)+T(x_2)$ and $T(\alpha x)=\alpha T(x)$.

Claim (3):

> $T$ is linear.

Claim (4):

> $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle = \langle Tx,x\rangle$

This follows since $\langle x-Tx,Tx\rangle=0$, from claim (2), since $Tx\in Y$.

Comment: The second claim I know it right? since I know that the orthogonal projection exists and is unique.

Comment: But your definition was about distance, not orthogonality. You have to start from your definition. @user162343

Comment: And where is the proof of linearity? thanks :)

Comment: Well I have another theorem that says, $y_0$ is the orthogonal projection, iff $x-y_0 \in Y^\prep$

Comment: Linearity, as I say, follows from (2) above. It's easy to show that $x_1+x_2-Tx_1-Tx_2$ is orthogonal to every element of $Y$, and hence $T(x_1+x_2)=Tx_1+Tx_2$.

Comment: and what do you think of my above comment :)?

Comment: Which comment. Be specific, there are lots of comments here, and none seem to require me to have an opinion about them.

Comment: Sorry, the 4th of this answer.

Comment: Again, you are asking me to work too hard, sorting through comments. And you do you mean fourth total, or fourth of yours? Help me help you.

Comment: Ok, sorry again, well, I have the result that says that $y_0$ is the orthogonal projection iff $ x − y _0 ⊥ Y$ . then this is the second claim right?

Comment: Yes that is equivalent to my claim (2), and linearity follows from either.

Comment: Ok :) let me check it, if I have further questions Can I let you know?

Comment: Oh, one more thing, can you help me with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514514/proving-two-facts-of-this-space please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use comments on one answer to ask for help on another. Comments are not for chatting.

Comment: Sorry, so what do I have to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

$\color{red}{\textbf{I find a simple froof }}$

from [real and complex analysis, theorem 4.11, page 80] by rudin, we know that for Hilbert space H and $x\in H$, we have
$$\|x\|^2=\|P_Y(x)\|^2+\|x-P_Y(x)\|^2$$
this means that
$$ \|P_Y(x)\|\leq  \|x\| $$
and hence, $  P_Y(x) $ is continuous.